# Obtain the lexicographically smallest string possible, by using at most P points

Tags: c#

⦁   Replace and/or re-arrange characters of this given string to get the lexicographically smallest string possible. For this, you can perform the following two operations any number of times.

⦁   Swap any two characters in the string. This operation costs 1 point. (any two, need not be adjacent)
⦁   Replace a character in the string with any other lower case English letter. This operation costs 2 points.

Obtain the lexicographically smallest string possible, by using at most P points.

Input:
⦁   Two lines of input, first-line containing two integers N, P.
⦁   The second line contains a string S consisting of N characters.

Output:
Lexicographically smallest string obtained.
for e.g

```
Sample Input:
3 3
bba
Sample Output:
aab
```

Ive tried this but it doesnt contain P points i dont know how to do that can you guys please help me with that:

```
namespace Lexicographical
{
class GFG
{

    // Function to return the lexicographically 
    // smallest String that can be formed by 
    // swapping at most one character. 
    // The characters might not necessarily 
    // be adjacent. 
    static String findSmallest(char[] s)
    {
        int len = s.Length;

        // Store last occurrence of every character 
        int[] loccur = new int[26];

        // Set -1 as default for every character. 
        for (int i = 0; i < 26; i++)
            loccur[i] = -1;

        for (int i = len - 1; i >= 0; --i)
        {

            // char index to fill 
            // in the last occurrence array 
            int chI = s[i] - 'a';
            if (loccur[chI] == -1)
            {

                // If this is true then this 
                // character is being visited 
                // for the first time from the last 
                // Thus last occurrence of this 
                // character is stored in this index 
                loccur[chI] = i;
            }
        }

        char[] sorted_s = s;
        Array.Sort(sorted_s);

        for (int i = 0; i < len; ++i)
        {
            if (s[i] != sorted_s[i])
            {

                // char to replace 
                int chI = sorted_s[i] - 'a';

                // Find the last occurrence 
                // of this character. 
                int last_occ = loccur[chI];

                // Swap this with the last occurrence 
                char temp = s[last_occ];
                s[last_occ] = s[i];
                s[i] = temp;
                break;
            }
        }

        return String.Join("", s);
    }

    // Driver code 
    public static void Main(String[] args)
    {
        String s = "abb";
        Console.Write(findSmallest(s.ToCharArray()));
    }
}
}
```

The output for this is abb but it should be aab...
I want to know how i can use above Question in this

Comment: Did you debug your program step by step ?

Comment: my program works only for swapping but not for replacements